# How to instantiate struct that is defined in different package from struct name and provide fields

Tags: go, struct, reflection

Suppose I have some `struct`s defined in package `pkg`:

```
package pkg

type Foo struct {
    FieldA string
    FieldB string
}

type Bar struct {
    FieldA string
    FieldB string
}

func (Foo) Show() {
    fmt.Println("Foo")
}

func (Bar) Show() {
    fmt.Println("Bar")
}

type Showable interface {
    Show()
}

Registry := map[string]Showable{
//not sure about value type^
    "Foo": Foo,     // staticcheck shows: not a type
    "Bar": Bar,     //
}
```

And I want to instantiate the `struct`s dynamically; something like this:

```
package main

import "url/user/pkg"

func main() {
    foo := pkg.Registry["Foo"]{
        FieldA: "A",
        FieldB: "B",
    }
    
    bar := pkg.Registry["Bar"]{
        FieldA: "X",
        FieldB: "Y",
    }
    foo.Show()
    bar.Show()
}
```

The above clearly doesn't work.

Is it possible to achieve this? I am new to [go](/questions/tagged/go). I have looked at `reflect`, I have tried to build the `Registry` with pointers, pointers of empty instance, but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Ultimately, I am trying to write a command line utility to change themes of certain programs. I have written program specific methods (like Show in above example), and I am trying to read the program specific params from a config.json file, and create the instances dynamically.

Comment: I see HOW you are trying to implement something, but it clearly won't work in GO. Could you please clarify WHAT you are trying to implement?

Comment: Sure. So basically I am trying to write a command line utility to change themes of certain programs. I have written program specific methods (like `Show` in above example), and I am trying to read the program specific params from a config.json file, and create the instances dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, here is
the way to do that:

`registry.go`:

```
package pkg

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

type NewShowable func(r io.Reader) Showable

type Showable interface {
    Show()
}

type Foo struct {
    FieldA string
    FieldB string
}

func newFoo(r io.Reader) Showable {
    // Read config from r and construct Foo
    return Foo{}
}

func (Foo) Show() {
    fmt.Println("Foo")
}

type Bar struct {
    FieldA string
    FieldB string
}

func newBar(r io.Reader) Showable {
    // Read config from r and construct Bar
    return Bar{}
}

func (Bar) Show() {
    fmt.Println("Bar")
}

var Registry = map[string]NewShowable{
    "Foo": newFoo,
    "Bar": newBar,
}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "url/user/pkg"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("config.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    foo := pkg.Registry["Foo"](f)

    f2, err := os.Open("config2.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer f2.Close()
    bar := pkg.Registry["Bar"](f2)
    foo.Show()
    bar.Show()
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks! Btw, would you say this is a bad pattern wrt to [tag:go] ?

Comment: I don't see anything sinister in that. The standard library uses similar registries. For example, the "sql" package uses a registry allowing third-party packages to add their named SQL drivers to it: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=44

Comment: In other words, if you expect that some third-party package can extend the registry, then this approach makes sense. Otherwise, I don't see a value in it yet.